# Oracle apex classic report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can i create oracle classic report use this oracle function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function HR.pivot_func
     return     sys_refcursor
   as
     v_sql     varchar2 (32767);
     v_refcur  sys_refcursor;
   begin
     v_sql :=
        'select *
         from     (select current_position,
                fk_department,
                wages
             from     emp)
         pivot  (sum (wages)
            for fk_department in (';
     for r in
        (select distinct fk_department
         from     emp)
     loop
        v_sql := v_sql || '''' || r.fk_department || ''',';
     end loop;
     v_sql := rtrim (v_sql, ',') || ')) order  by 1';
     open v_refcur for v_sql;
     return v_refcur;
   end pivot_func;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Classic Report **based on function**.